# How to get LocalNotification PhoneGap plugin working?

Tags: iphone, cordova, localnotification

I'm trying to get the LocalNotification plugin working (for either ios or android), but am having trouble finding the right documentation. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or what I need to add? I'm trying the following:

Added the plugin using the following from the command line

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git
```

Tried both of the following in the config.xml:

```
<plugin name="LocalNotification" value="LocalNotification" />
```

and

```
<feature name="LocalNotification">
    <param name="ios-package" value="LocalNotification"/>
</feature>
```

Added local-notification.js to the www folder and included it in the index.html file with the following:

```
<script src="local-notification.js"></script>
```

And have the following to use the plugin in the controller (I'm using Angular):

```
$scope.localNotify = function(){
        var d = new Date();
        d = d.getTime() + 5*1000; //60 seconds from now
        d = new Date(d);
        window.plugins.localNotification.add({
            date: d,
            repeat:'daily',
            message: 'This just fired after a minute!',
            hasAction: true,
            badge: 1,
            id: '1',
            sound:'horn.caf',
            background:'app.background',
            foreground:'app.running'
        });
    };
```

I see in the readme here https://github.com/simplec-dev/LocalNotification/blob/45867c94ee96aaa90966d22b62acabfc03807cb3/README.md they say to modify CDVPlugin.m and CDVPlugin.h, but I don't see these files anywhere in my project.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Those files should be in your /plugins/***/ folder.

Comment: Thanks, MBillau, found the files! I got it working per the comments below and using your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working! I'm not sure if it's because the version I was using was meant for an earlier version of PhoneGap, but I found this repo 
https://github.com/hiattp/Phonegap-LocalNotification, followed the directions there, and now it's working. Didn't need to make any edits to config.xml, add a localnotification.js file, or make any changes to index.html. Just followed the directions at that link and it works!

Comment: I have tried the same. As per your comment localnotification.js was not added or reference in the index.html page and no plugins were added to the config.xml file. Still nothing turned up correctly. Could you give me some insight of what exact steps you took.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Cordova device plugin:

```
phonegap local plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

Answer (score 0):

For the record (cause I was stuck here).
You were building a PhoneGap iOS project not a Cordova iOS project 
and then using a Cordova (only) project.
To build in PhoneGap:
`phonegap build ios`

To build in Cordova:
`cordova platform add ios`

The PhoneGap plugin you referenced: https://github.com/hiattp/Phonegap-LocalNotification

Is the most uptodate so use that!